# BeanCreationException error updating Spring boot version 2.2.7.RELEASE to 2.7.0

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud

I added like this:

```xml
<properties>
    <spring-boot.version>2.7.0</spring-boot.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<!-- ... -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ... -->
</dependencies>
```

After running it I got this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3b192d32]
> ...........
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3b19

> Sprinframework.cloud versions appear at version 2.2.7 in dependencies after Maven clean, install :

[maven dependencies here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXCOK.png)

How can I resolve this error,thanks.

Comment: You've still got a mixed environment. Most spring cloud versions will be 3.1.x. What still had 2.2.x? Can you post your spring cloud dependencies by editing the question?